# 301 redirect – When old url contains questions mark, delivers 404 page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have created 301 redirects to our old pages to new pages through yoast seo.

However, if the old url contains ? then it delivers 404 page. Can someone help me fix this.

This is on wordpress.

Example:

```
301 redirect  /products/ABC **GOES TO** /shop/all-products/ABC
```

But
/products/ABC?sscid=41k5_18bqo **GOES TO** 404

Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

Place this following Rule at the top of your htaccess file.
Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(products.*)$ shop/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: @Divyanshu Bajpai, could you please do let me know if code has worked for you?